# Env variables from configmap not available inside pod

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, kubectl

I am trying to pass env variable to my pod from configmap. I have the following setup.

I have a file **test-config.txt** with 2 env variables

```
a_sample_env=b
c_sample_env=d
```

I create a configmap as follows:

> kubectl create configmap test-config --from-file test-config.txt

My pod definition is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: redis
    envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: test-config
```

But my application doesn't receive the 2 env variables in the test-config.txt file. I logged into the pod using kubectl exec and get empty values for the env variables.

```
root@test-pod:/data# echo $c_sample_env

root@test-pod:/data# echo $a_sample_env
```

Can anybody point out why the environment variables are not available in the pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create configmap as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
  namespace: default
data:
  a_sample_env: b
  c_sample_env: d
```

if you create configmap using below command

```
kubectl create configmap test-config --from-file test-config.txt
```

then you can mount test-config as volume inside container. You will have to create a wrapper/launch script to export all k:v pair from that file as env variable during startup

Comment: the command `kubectl create configmap test-config --from-env-file test-config.txt` worked for me. It created a yaml as you mentioned above.

Comment: @Malathi I don't see what was the problem here. Can you explain how this answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the secret using `--from-literal` flag instead of `--from-file`

```
kubectl create cm test-config --from-literal=a_sample_env=b --from-literal=c_sample_env=d
```

Create the pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: test-pod
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: redis
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: test-pod
    resources: {}
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: test-config
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

Exec to the pod and check the envs

```
root@test-pod:/data# env | grep sample
c_sample_env=d
a_sample_env=b
```